# Deleting all custom CRS from QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3

I am using a custom CRS for a project and whenever I load a .shp file, QGIS (3.8.2) creates a new custom CRS entry. As of today, I have about 10000 entries that are all the same and would like to delete them.
Can I do it all at once? Clicking the minus sign is becoming tedious, since there is about a second of delay between each click.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Custom crs are stored is a sqlite database table `tbl_srs`. The database itself is under your profile path and the file is called `qgis.db`. So, it should be safe to delete the rows of the table. To do that, close QGIS, make a copy of that db-file (if something goes wrong...), and open `qgis.db` in a sqlite-database sql-monitor, like [spatialite-gui](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite_gui/home) or [sqlitebrowser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/). Then you can use a sql expression to delete the rows. For example `DELETE FROM tbl_srs` removes all entries in the table. Make sure to disconnect your sql-monitor from the database (close it) and start qgis again.